# What's the best Magento version for PHP Version 5.2.17

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento2

My current hosting have PHP version 5.2.17 and MySQL version 5.6.26, It's shared hosting and I can not upgrade to the PHP 5.6, So .. What is the best "stable" version of Magento CE can I work on?

Comment: Please, please, please, change your hosting. This is not going to end well

Comment: Why are you stuck with a hosting provider that cannot provide a secure ecommerce hosting environment that supports a currently security patched version of PHP? This is not a good business plan for either you or your customers.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to like it but Community edition 1.4 or 1.5 is about all you have to choose from.

Your options are not good. I agree with fschmengier, you should consider new hosting.

The versions of Magento that are that old are not very good, as compared to 1.8 and 1.9.

Comment: As a note: Those versions of CE are not longer receiving security patches if I remember correctly. So it's an extra bad idea.

Comment: I agree 100% but he asked what are his options. I begrudgingly offered them.

Comment: I find it strange that his host will have a brand new version of mysql yet an antiquated version of php?!

Comment: Most likely the OPs host offers different hosting packages for different purposes and this is the wrong one. I cant see someone getting a good Magento install out of less than mid-cost shared hosting account. If the OP asks the host there are probably options.